# Illustrator: Rotate multiple objects to one point

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, illustrator-scripting, rotate

I'm wondering if there is a way to rotate multiple objects to one point in Illustrator. I already know about blending and Transform Each.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice script that can do just this called [Rotate Toward Point by Hiroyuki Sato](http://shspage.blogspot.com/2014/02/rotatetowardpointjsx.html)

[image]

The script rotates the objects in the selection toward the center of the foreground object.

[image]

Give it a try and see how you like the results!

### NOTE:

This is not a perfect solution. You can't select *every* arrow and have it magically work. You will need to play around with the selections and run it in groups to achieve the effect.

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution is to make a pattern brush:

[image]

The blue shape is dragged to the brushes collection and defined to be a pattern brush with 40% spacing. The brush is applied to a bunch of rounded squares. They were created using Object > Blend.

Drawbacks:

- very difficult to predefine the places of the shapes, needs math
- only a predefined set of shapes (here only 1)
- curved lines distort the shapes

Comment: Really creative idea, love it. Thank you, I'll try this out!