# Illustrator: Rotate a group of paths randomly and individually about the groups center

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, transform, rotate

Basically, how do I do a hybrid of Rotate which rotates every object in a selection  a fixed [there is no random option here] amount about the selection's center, and Transform Each> Rotate[random] which rotates each selected object individually but only about each object's own center.

What I want is either the ability to chose Random in Rotate and have it apply to **each object** in the selection **independently**, or want the ability to move the Transform Each rotation point for the selected objects to a common point prior to application.

Edit: [Added Image]
The idea is a group of objects each individually rotate a randomly determined amount about a given axis [or a group axis], while keeping their orientation facing the axis

[image]

Comment: First Google result: https://medium.com/@12yan/random-rotate-illustrator-script-2a8bcaa7087f

Comment: Sorry, that rotates each one about its own axis, not the common one.

Comment: Then: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/108742/illustrator-rotate-multiple-objects-to-one-point

Comment: No, I saw that and that is rotating a object about its own axis to point to a point. I will add a illustration to hopefully clarify things.

Comment: That'll help `:)` So far you don't want them rotated around their own center... and you don't want them rotated to a common focal point... I'm left thinking the only other option would be to rotate multiple objects in unison, so they all rotate the same amount.

Comment: I want them rotating around a common point, but each one a random angle. 

Imagine a bunch of kids around a Maypole and you told each of them to run around it a random amount.

Comment: ahhh.. "keep orientation" was the part I was missing. Not certain if that's possible.. hmm...

Comment: Thanks for working on it, I can sort of do it in AutoCAD with scripting, which is where I will switch to if I can't figure out a way to do in Illustrator. The goal is to make a replica of an very old Kellog's Cereal Toy which used this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if this will work for you, but it's as close as I can think. Perhaps another user will know of a script or better method.

A **Scatter Brush** -- this assume the objects, like your example are all similar. If they are *not* similar, disregard everything after this sentence. `:)` This won't work for anything more than placement reference. I doubt that's overly helpful.

---

<sub>(CS6 screenshots, but it's similar in newer versions)</sub>

- Drag one shape to the **Brushes Panel**
- Choose `Scatter Brush` when asked.
- In the `Scatter Brush Options` window that appears set the `Rotation relative to` to **path** rather than the default "page".
- Click OK

Draw a circle and apply the new scatter brush to it. You should get the circle with the objects rotated relative to the central point of the circle.

[image]

- Select this circle and click the **Brush Options** button at the bottom of the **Brushes Panel**
- Tick preview if necessary
- Set the `Scatter` field to **Random**

[image]

- Adjust the sliders on either side of the field

This will result in random dispersement of the objects but they will all still be rotated relative to the path.

You can then expand the appearance of the brush and alter the appearance of individual object instances.

Here's an animation showing it all....

[image]

---

Again, I don't know if this will work for you. I'm assuming the objects are more than merely hexagons perhaps.

Also note I used a circle as the basis for the brush. **Any path** could be used and the rotate will remain relative to it.

Comment: This should work...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still time to show a workaround, but there is a tool in Illustrator called `Transform Each` that can do exactly what you need.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POVyHHiQ9CE) explains how to use it:

But I'll leave here a quick tutorial with images:

First, arrange your objects however you like on the artboard.
Then select all (they cannot be grouped) and go to `Object > Transform > Transform Each`

[image: first image]

Within the window there are several options. One of them is `Random`. Check this option, also check `Preview` and configure the options in the way that works best for you.

[image: first image]

And that's it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi  This does not allow putting the pivot where you want.